# The named parameter 'title' isn't defined

Tags: flutter, dart

I get this error for the 'title' on the second line:

The named parameter 'title' isn't defined.
Try correcting the name to an existing named parameter's name, or defining a named parameter with the name 'title'.

```dart
textTheme: ThemeData.light().textTheme.copyWith(
                  title: TextStyle(
                    fontFamily: 'OpenSans',
                    fontSize: 20,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  ),
```

Comment: And is it defined in `copyWith`?

Comment: yes. the problem was that "title"  is depricated and no longer useful

Answer (score 1):

With the latest version of Flutter, some theme identifiers changed.

```
display4 => headline1;
display3 => headline2;
display2 => headline3;
display1 => headline4;
headline => headline5;
title    => headline6; // so use headline6 instead of title
subhead  => subtitle1;
subtitle => subtitle2;
body2    => bodyText1; 
body     => bodyText2;
```

So you can define your Theme like this:

```
textTheme: ThemeData.light().textTheme.copyWith(
                  headline6: TextStyle(
                    fontFamily: 'OpenSans',
                    fontSize: 20,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  ),
```

and then use it e.g. like this:

```
Text(
    'my text',
    style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline6,
   ),
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `titleLarge`, `titleMedium` and  `titleSmall` in place of `title`, use `.copyWith()` constructor.

```dart
return MaterialApp(
  title: 'MyApp',
  theme: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
    textTheme: ThemeData.light().textTheme.copyWith(
      titleSmall: Theme.of(context).textTheme.titleLarge?.copyWith(
                    fontFamily: 'OpenSans',
                    fontSize: 20,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  ),
       titleLarge: Theme.of(context).textTheme.titleLarge?.copyWith(...),
       titleMedium: Theme.of(context).textTheme.titleLarge?.copyWith(...),
```

Answer (score 0):

TextTheme does not include title /As you see in the below image:/
[TextTheme properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/inx8E.png)

You can set theme like this

```
textTheme: TextTheme(
  headline1: TextStyle(fontSize: 24, color: lightColors.PRIMARY_TEXT_COLOR, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
  headline2: TextStyle(fontSize: 22, color: lightColors.PRIMARY_TEXT_COLOR, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
  headline3: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: lightColors.PRIMARY_TEXT_COLOR, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
  headline4: TextStyle(fontSize: 17, color: lightColors.PRIMARY_TEXT_COLOR, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
  headline5: TextStyle(fontSize: 16, color: lightColors.PRIMARY_TEXT_COLOR, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
  headline6: TextStyle(fontSize: 15, color: lightColors.PRIMARY_TEXT_COLOR, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
  subtitle1: TextStyle(fontSize: 14, color: lightColors.PRIMARY_TEXT_COLOR, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
  subtitle2: TextStyle(fontSize: 12, color: lightColors.PRIMARY_TEXT_COLOR, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
  bodyText1: TextStyle(fontSize: 14, color: lightColors.PRIMARY_TEXT_COLOR, fontWeight: FontWeight.normal),
  bodyText2: TextStyle(fontSize: 13, color: lightColors.SECONDARY_TEXT_COLOR, fontWeight: FontWeight.normal),
  button: TextStyle(fontSize: 15, color: lightColors.GRAY_COLOR_100)
),
```

And use it in your App

```
Text("Text", style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle1!.copyWith())
```

Answer (score 0):

The **"title"** is now deprecated, use **"label"** property instead

Documentation:
https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/bottom-navigation-title-to-label